# Operators close in $L_2$ norm. Can anything be said about Euclidean norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote a vector space of functions $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let $\Vert \phi \Vert$ denote the $L_2$ norm, i.e. 
\begin{equation}
\Vert \phi \Vert = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\phi(x)|^2d\mu(x)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}},
\end{equation}
$d\mu$ the Lebesgue measure.

Consider the bounded linear operators $K_1:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}$ and $K_2:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}$ that satisfy:
\begin{equation}
\Vert K_1\phi - K_2\phi \Vert \leq \epsilon.
\end{equation}
Can anything be said about the points $K_1\phi(x)$ and $K_2\phi(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

In other words, is there a result that relates the quantity $\Vert K_1\phi(x) - K_2\phi(x)\Vert_2$, where $\Vert x \Vert_2$ is the Euclidean norm, to the quantity $\Vert K_1\phi - K_2\phi \Vert$?

Comment: Hunch: I don't think you can say much of anything about that distance. The problem is that you have no conditions on $\phi,$  such as Lipshitz. $\phi$ can be pretty much about anything.

Comment: @AdrianKeister . The members of the $L_2$ space are not functions but equivalence classes of functions, where $f\equiv g$ iff $f,g$ agree almost everywhere. So if $K_1\phi $ is a member of the $L_2$ space there isn't really a number $(K_1\phi)(x)$ for any given $x$